# Determine the largest element at particular index of all array for the first Q indexes

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Given several arrays that contain natural numbers less than `M`. The size of each array may vary, but the sum of all size of arrays must be `N`. Determine the largest element at particular index of all array for the first `Q` indexes start from `0`. If the index is larger than the size of array, then the index is modulo by its size.

Constraint:

```
N <= 50000
M <= 32
Q <= 1000000
```

Example :

```
N = 6
M = 4
array1 = [0,1,3]
array2 = [2,0]
array3 = [1]
Q = 6

Results = [2,1,3,1,2,3]
Explanation : At index 3, the largest element from array1[3%3], array2[3%2], and array3[3%1] is 1.
```

I know the `O(√N * Q)` solution by simply iterate all array from `0` to `Q` indexes, but I need faster solution. Maybe by benefiting the constraint `M` in such a way might provide faster solution, but still can't figure it out.

Comment: Could you explain how you get O(√N * Q) ?

Comment: @d40a First combine arrays that have same size. Then each index from `0` to `Q-1`, iterate all array using `array[index%array.size()]` to get the largest element. It may looks like `O(N*Q)`, but if we combine first, the worst case must be arrays that have incremental size `[1,2,3,4,...]` and the sum size is `N`. By using the formula of arithmetic series, the number of arrays is approximately `√2N`. cmiiw.